# Unique message for each permission combined via bitwise operator in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Question is about getting unique message in case of multiple permissions used in DRF.

For example I have 2 following permissions classes:

```
class PermOne(permissions.IsAuthenticated):
   
    message = ‘message one’

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.entry_author == request.user


class PermTwo(permissions.IsAuthenticated):
   
    message = ‘message two’

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return request.user.is_active


class MyView( generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (PermOne |PermTwo)
…
…
…
```

Problem is if I combine 2 or more remission with operators like `| &`, in case of failure instead of unique message defined in each permission class, I receive standard

```
 {
    "detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."
}
```

, whereas in case of only single permission class message is taken from permission class successfully.

Of course I can combine 2 permission in one class and define message choice logic inside this class, but it ok for 2 perms, and what about 5? Seem like it against the flow.

Anyway, is it possible to provide unique message being used for each permission class in case of combining them via `|` or `&`???

Thank you!

Comment: There is no method to do this (at least till now). When DRF check the permissions, it considers it as a single class and that ***virtual permission class*** doesn't have any **`message`** attribute in it.

Comment: @Arakkal Abu. Thank you for the answer. Do you know where i could find code on 'virtual permission class'??

Comment: Source Code: [Operator supported permission classes](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/permissions.py)

Comment: [Permission classes are being executed from view](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/7a04269209d398a79fe5969044fab27470808f47/rest_framework/views.py#L274)

Comment: [raises permission error and return custom messages if conditions are not met](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/7a04269209d398a79fe5969044fab27470808f47/rest_framework/views.py#L326)